# Raw domain call not accessable anymore after "Deny from all" and just allow "index.php"

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url

I've tried to avoid access files on my webspace in general. Only the `index.php` should be allowed. I don't want to reach this goal without using `mod_rewrite`. My actual code is the following:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1

<Files /index.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

It works when I'm calling my website like www.example.com/index.php, but it doesn't work when I leave the `index.php` from the URL like www.example.com/

I thought the Apache webserver would know to use the `index.php` when no segment to the URL is added.

Can you help me out here to understand it and tell `.htaccess` to allow a raw domain-call?

Comment: This isn't instagram, you know? xD Edit your title to be more descriptive.

Comment: LOOOOL! Fail of the year... Thanks man for the hint. Do you also have an answer for me or anyone else?

Comment: No, I am just going through the review atm and I noticed the hashtags in your title :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you better have to use some regular expressions to solve this issue

using `<FilesMatch>` tag instead of `<Files>` tag

```
<FilesMatch "^(index\.php)?$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Thank you. Since I added your code it works. But can you explain why your code works for raw domain calls?
In my opinion your code usually tells the apache to grant access to files which start with "index.." right?

Comment: you are welcome buddy, yes you are right , but it's tells apache to grant access to files start [and end ] with 'index.php'